# Creating integration tests on classes with dependency injection

Tags: java, testing, dependency-injection, integration-testing

I have a Java EE web application that heavily relies on dependency injection.

Currently it works as expected and it is injecting everything the way I want it to in production and I can without too much hassle inject mock objects when I am writing unit tests.

However I now want to create integration tests so that I know that the entire flow is working and it is getting and parsing correct data from other APIs.

The problem I am seeing now is with solving dependency injection in a test environment, because it is an integration test there are a lot more dependencies to solve, So doing this manually does not seem feasible.

So, How is this usually solved? for reference I am using a mix of `@EJB` and `@Inject` to inject `Objects`.

Comment: Why are you having problems with dependency injection in a test environment? It should be essentially the same environment as your production environment, except using less data and mocking some external services for various purposes.

Comment: I might have been unclear, with test environment i mean running the tests, not deploying to a seperate environment. So I am not getting the injection that is otherwise solved if I "actually run" the application

Comment: Test environment doesn't necessarily mean a separate physical environment that you'd deploy into.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack workaround that I'll use till I figure out how it "should" be done:

```
    private static Map<Class, Object> instances = new HashMap<>();
    public static <T> T getInstance(Class<T> type) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        if(instances.containsKey(type))
            return (T)instances.get(type);
        T res = type.newInstance();
        instances.put(type, res);
        for(Field field : type.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Inject.class) || field.isAnnotationPresent(EJB.class)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(res, getInstance(field.getType()));
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Are you performing your own injection? If so, why?

Comment: In this case yes, because the normal injection handling is not triggered when I run the tests.

Comment: Your test framework is supposed to handle the injection, not you.